# Docker .NET 6 image magic file

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, dockerfile

I create a default ASP.NET Core 6 MVC project in Visual Studio 2022 with checkbox "docker -linux". After docker build -> run image all work fine!

But I find in image magic file which take 129kb with name equal project name.

- I haven't seen this file in my project!
- I don't have this file, and I try to run it without docker, execute cmd command `dotnet restore -> dotnet publish`!

I try remove this file from container by hand and after restart all work fine without this file.

What is magic file ? How I can make docker images without this file? Interesting this unnecessary file takes 1/2 ALL MY application folder space...

This file doesn't have any extension, this file is binary (I think).

List of files:

[image]

Cat head:

[image]

Comment: @HansKilian  It 's not true , I recorded a video for you:  https://ibb.co/3cpNGx7

Comment: Small question - are 129 kb that critical?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you publish an app, by default dotnet creates both a platform-dependent executable and a platform-independent dll.

The `web1` file is the platform-dependent executable and `web1.dll` is the platform-independent dll.

You can get publish to not create the platform-dependent executable by adding the following section to your .csproj file

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <UseAppHost>false</UseAppHost>
</PropertyGroup>
```

More info here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#useapphost

Comment: thx! its work. i dont know about that .netsdk images made difference build\publish that my personal .netsdk